# Why isn't my outputstream in Java being read/received by my PHP file

Tags: java, php, android

I'm trying to perform a simple query in PHP which takes parameters from a Java class. The Java Class is part of an Android phone app I am working on. I am able to make a connection and receive an input stream from the PHP file, which I have been using to see the exact error that my app receives. The error is "Undefined index: username".

I have tested the PHP file by typing the parameters directly into the URL, which has worked, and using a URL with the parameters hard-coded in also works. However, I want to perform different queries, not the same one every time, so I need to be able to pass my parameters in my output stream.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LoginSupport extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    private TextView progress;

    public LoginSupport(TextView progress) {
        this.progress = progress;

    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        try {
            //get login values
            String username =  arg0[0];
            //add login values to string
            String data  = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
            //pass login values to PHP file
            String urlString = "http://192.**.**.**/App.php?";  //IP address hidden
            URL urlForLogin = new URL(urlString);
            URLConnection UrlConn = urlForLogin.openConnection();
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) UrlConn;
            httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
            httpConn.setDoInput(true);
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/text; charset=utf-8");

            //The OutputStreamWriter wr passes the string containing encoded parameters to the php file.

            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(httpConn.getOutputStream());

            /*This is another methods, which hasnt worked...
            OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(httpConn.getOutputStream());
            BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "utf-8"));
             ...and here is another that didnt work...
            PrintWriter wr = new PrintWriter(httpConn.getOutputStream(), true);
            wr.print(data); */

            wr.write(data);
            System.out.println(data);  //I used this to check that what was being sent to the server was what I expected. (it is)


            //Opens a stream to receive the query response.
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getInputStream()));
            //Read query response.
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            //the following if statement gets ignored for some reason, unless I use "==".
            if (line.equals("Connected")){
                this.progress.setText("It worked!");
            }else{
                this.progress.setText("Failed");
            }
            wr.close();
            reader.close();
            httpConn.disconnect();
            return "true";

        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
    }

}
```

My PHP file uses $username = $_POST['username']; to read the parameter.

Sources I have used:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html
- [HTTPURLConnection - Outputstream POST to php on webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33662043/httpurlconnection-outputstream-post-to-php-on-webserver)
- [How to pass an argument with POST using HttpUrlConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324156/how-to-pass-an-argument-with-post-using-httpurlconnection)
- https://www.blackbaud.com/files/support/guides/infinitydevguide/content/java/cocreateaconnectionwithurlconnection.htm
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm
- Days of Googling

Comment: I'm confused. Why wouldn't you just have the Java program put the correct information into the URL/post parameters?

Comment: I notice you're setting the `Content-Type` to `application/text`. PHP [requires](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) either `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` for `$_POST` to be filled automatically.

Comment: Close the `Writer` to mark the content complete, *before* attempting to read the response. --- *Hint:* Use try-with-resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[rickdenhaan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53342661/why-isnt-my-outputstream-in-java-being-read-received-by-my-php-file/53343978#comment93564383_53342661) helped me solve this.

I changed

```
httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/text; charset=utf-8");
```

to

```
httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```